# Propper way to set anchor and url param

Tags: permalinks, links

I need to make a link between to pages, (HOME-> CustomPost Archive) where in the second page esist a form, so I want to go directly to the form.
so i made somethink like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'consulta' ) ?>#form">
    <?php echo $consult->post_title ?>
</a>
```

and all its fine.

But now I need to send the id of the selected post to the form, with a url param, like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'consulta' ) ?>?consulta=<?php echo $consult->ID ?>#form">
    <?php echo $consult->post_title ?>
</a>
```

but this, result on 404 error.

also if I change the order of the params in the url like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'consulta' ) ?>#form?consulta=<?php echo $consult->ID ?>">
    <?php echo $consult->post_title ?>
</a>
```

the Id, is working OK, but not the anchor link.

Any idea on how to solve this?

**UPDATE** the loop

```
<?php
    $args     = array(
        'post_type' => 'consulta',
    );
    $consults = get_posts( $args );
?>

        <div class="consultation-items">
            <?php foreach ( $consults as $consult ):
                $category = wp_get_object_terms( $consult->ID,  'consult_category' );
                $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $consult ) ?>

                <div class="grid-item-row">
                    <div class="grid-item">
                        <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'consulta' ) ?>#consulta-form?consulta=<?php echo $consult->ID ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumb ?>"></a></div>
                        <div class="item-info">
                            <p><?php echo $category[0]->name ?> </p>
                            <h4>
                                <a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'consulta' ) ?>#consulta-form?consulta=<?php echo $consult->ID ?>">
                                    <?php echo $consult->post_title ?>
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>
```

Comment: can you tell us what the actual code output is?

Comment: @rudtek I don't understand what you asking for, this is my actual code

Comment: i see the code (but I don't know if you're in a loop as you've only given part of the code) but what I'm looking for is the output.  What is the link that results when you run the code.  ie what do you see on the frontend?  what is the actual link?

Comment: @rudtek, its inside a loop I update th question with the loop

Comment: What is the purpose of `consulta=` in the URL? That's what's causing the 404. You are querying for a `consulta` post with slug that matches a post's ID, which I'm guessing is not what you are expecting.

Comment: @Milo, In the home pagee, I show the list of this post_type with the code above, the when I click this link, this redirectme to a form page, with a select box, where the item selected its the item clicked, so to do this I have to pass the ID of this item from one page to another, and this is the only way that I found

Comment: you need to change your code to use something other than `consulta`. add a letter, remove a letter, use a different word, It just has to be unique.

Comment: @Milo, ok thanks!! its working now, you can post it as an answer to give you the upvotes

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'consulta' ).'?consulta='.$consult->ID.'#form'; ?>"
```

Comment: same result, thinks that its no problem with the url, maybe something whith the permalinks